# I would like to pass an array from my main method to my function(min) so that the minimum can be calculated in the function(min)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, integer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int pArray[], int nrOfArrayElements)
{
    min = pArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nrOfArrayElements; i++)
    {
        if (pArray[i] < min)
        {
            min = pArray[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int main()
{
    int x[10] = { 2,3,4,5,1,6,9,8,7,0 };
    int sizeOfArray, sizeOfElement, nrOfArrayElements;

    sizeOfArray = sizeOf(x);
    sizeOfElement = sizeOf(x[0]);
    nrOfArrayElements = sizeOfArray / sizeOfElement;
    int min = min(x[10],nrOfArrayElements);
    printf("smallest Array = %d", min);
    return 0;
}
```

The following errors appear whilst trying to pass my array from main to my function min im not quite sure why pArray[0] is classified as a pointer when I am just trying to get the element on that position.

main.c:13:9: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
min = pArray[0];

main.c:19:8: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
min = pArray[i];

main.c:32:16: error: called object ‘min’ is not a function or function pointer
int min = min(x[10],nrOfArrayElements);

Comment: Please try to find a better title

Comment: In the 5th line, declare a type for the min variable, also change it’s name to avoid confusion with the function name

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 problems.

1. You are calling function `sizeOf`, while the actual name is `sizeof`. (Note the Capitalization)
2. You are using an integer `min` and also a function `min`. Both identifiers cannot have the same name. I have changed the integer to `min2`.
3. In the function call to `min`, you are calling it with `min(x[10],nrOfArrayElements)`. Since the first parameter is an array of int, you need to pass the base address of the array, i.e. `min(x,nrOfArrayElements)`

Final code is below.

```
int min(int pArray[], int nrOfArrayElements)
{
    int min2;
    min2 = pArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nrOfArrayElements; i++)
    {
        if (pArray[i] < min2)
        {
            min2 = pArray[i];
        }
    }
    return min2;
}

int main()
{
    int x[10] = { 2,3,4,5,1,6,9,8,7,0 };
    int sizeOfArray, sizeOfElement, nrOfArrayElements;
    sizeOfArray = sizeof(x);
    sizeOfElement = sizeof(x[0]);
    nrOfArrayElements = sizeOfArray / sizeOfElement;
    int min2 = min(x,nrOfArrayElements);
    printf("smallest Array = %d", min2);
    return 0;
}
```